# Where is android contacts2.db mimetype "TYPE" stored in the data table i.e. not mimetype_id?

Tags: android, android-contacts

database contacts2.db from android has a table called data which has column called mimetype_id which correspond to the string representation found in another table called mimetypes.  However what I do not understand is: lets say we have an example with the Phone class directly taken from the package android.provider;

```
public static final class Phone implements ContactsContract.DataColumnsWithJoins, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.CommonColumns {
    public static final Uri CONTENT_FILTER_URI = null;
    public static final String CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE = "vnd.android.cursor.item/phone_v2";
    public static final String CONTENT_TYPE = "vnd.android.cursor.dir/phone_v2";
    public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = null;
    public static final Uri ENTERPRISE_CONTENT_FILTER_URI = null;
    public static final String EXTRA_ADDRESS_BOOK_INDEX = "android.provider.extra.ADDRESS_BOOK_INDEX";
    public static final String EXTRA_ADDRESS_BOOK_INDEX_COUNTS = "android.provider.extra.ADDRESS_BOOK_INDEX_COUNTS";
    public static final String EXTRA_ADDRESS_BOOK_INDEX_TITLES = "android.provider.extra.ADDRESS_BOOK_INDEX_TITLES";
    public static final String NORMALIZED_NUMBER = "data4";
    public static final String NUMBER = "data1";
    public static final String SEARCH_DISPLAY_NAME_KEY = "search_display_name";
    public static final String SEARCH_PHONE_NUMBER_KEY = "search_phone_number";
    public static final int TYPE_ASSISTANT = 19;
    public static final int TYPE_CALLBACK = 8;
    public static final int TYPE_CAR = 9;
    public static final int TYPE_COMPANY_MAIN = 10;
    public static final int TYPE_FAX_HOME = 5;
    public static final int TYPE_FAX_WORK = 4;
    public static final int TYPE_HOME = 1;
    public static final int TYPE_ISDN = 11;
    public static final int TYPE_MAIN = 12;
    public static final int TYPE_MMS = 20;
    public static final int TYPE_MOBILE = 2;
    public static final int TYPE_OTHER = 7;
    public static final int TYPE_OTHER_FAX = 13;
    public static final int TYPE_PAGER = 6;
    public static final int TYPE_RADIO = 14;
    public static final int TYPE_TELEX = 15;
    public static final int TYPE_TTY_TDD = 16;
    public static final int TYPE_WORK = 3;
    public static final int TYPE_WORK_MOBILE = 17;
    public static final int TYPE_WORK_PAGER = 18;
```

Now there we see different types for example “TYPE_ISDN = 11” or  TYPE_MOBILE = 2; I do understand that we have different data colums in the data table i.e. “data1” or “data4” in this case but where is the ISDN type information stored in the database. 
i.e. the question is : how can I tell directly from reading the data table if the phone I just read it is a mobile phone and not fax and vise versa . Where would be those integers 11 or 2 saved in this case? Since I have 5 phones for example and they are tagged with home, work, etc. etc.

Comment: you have `Phone#TYPE` column storing the type of the phone

Comment: weel i do not have a Phone#Type column but i found that this is saved in the data2 column

Comment: yes, you have [Phone#TYPE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.CommonColumns#TYPE), also see [Phone](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone) javadocs

Comment: ok got it that is the protected interface CommonColumns  now it makes sence.